# Multiplayer Seamless Open-World Chunks

Tags: multiplayer, mmo, godot-4, open-world, streaming

[there is a made a game called JDungeon](https://jonathaneeckhout.itch.io/jdungeon) that looks like this:

[image: Game screenshot]

I want to add seamless chunk loading and unloading, meaning instead of the black world boundary, a new chunk loads in seamlessly.

I'm trying to find a way to seamlessly load and unload chunks for a 2D multiplayer game project to make an open world with a working server using Godot 4.2.1.NET. Something similar to [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uE36MVjB5-8).

How can this work for multiplayer, and what is needed for this to potentially work? What options can be used for chunk loading and unloading seamlessly in Godot 4.2.1.NET?

Note: There seems to be at least 2 branches to solve this issue. One with baked navigation with a non-dynamic world and one with non-baked navigation with a dynamic world. I wonder if the baked navigation with a non-dynamic world solution would be easier but not very future proof and if what should be pursued is a solution with non-baked navigation with a dynamic world?

Comment: https://jonathaneeckhout.itch.io/jdungeon For the goal right now it is easy to play this but imagine it has seamless chunk loading and unloading. As instead of the black world boundary a new chunk loads in seamlessly. What are your suggestions and thoughts? *thinking*

Comment: "Note that you missed the first link." what what this mean, what have I missed? (Updated I fixed the first link here). Also Stardew valley is an example of light 2D dynamic world (plants and crops and terrain modification by the player) / some dynamic world features could be added. So I might have to do dynamic non-baked navigation anyway? As in also if I can do that it should also solve the cases for non-dynamic worlds too?

Comment: There are some details about Godot multiplayer I need to look up... I'll be writing an answer once I have a clearer idea.

Comment: Okay thank you. I also did some clean up of my posts to get more up to date and share all the links and demonstrations easier and with more clarity to help. Also thank you for helping too. Please ask any questions and say any thoughts and curiosities that I could do to help as well. I am more than motivated and willing to help. Feedback is always welcome!